# How to put more than one option for discordpy slashcommands?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I saw a feature for slashcommands that would be cool for my bot:
[image: slashcommand shows more options]

I tried passing more than one argument in the code, but both values became required for the command to run.

exemple:
`async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction, text:str, number:int)`

how can i turn this opcional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an argument optional, either give it a default value or type annotate it as `Optional`.

This is also in the official examples that you could've looked at: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/app_commands/basic.py#L68-L72

Comment: Tks, this import with exemple solve the problem <3